# regexp_replace vs regexp_substr and using moving data into many cells from one cell

Tags: input, output, buffer, teradata, limit

I keep getting a [Teradata Database] [9134] Output exceeds buffer limit.

```
select 
MHKAUDITLOGINTERNALID as id, 
Cast(MHK_CONTENT as CLOB)as MHK_CONTENT 
from vcoreMEDHOK_MHK_Audit 
Where cast(AUDITDATETIME as Date) >= '2021/08/15' )
--- and id ='31181086' )
select ID, regexp_replace(Token, '<b>|<\/b>') -- trim everything up to '<b>' 
FROM TABLE (RegExp_Split_To_Table(t.id, t.MHK_CONTENT,'<BR/> *', 'i') -- split whenever '<\/b>' occurs 
RETURNS ( id BIGINT, TokenNum INT, Token VARCHAR(35000) CHARACTER SET LATIN)) AS dt
```

Is anyone familiar with how to get around this?   [Teradata Database] [9134] Input exceeds the buffer size limit.

````
with t as
 (
   select MHKAUDITLOGINTERNALID  as id, cast(MHK_CONTENT as clob) as MHK_CONTENT
   from vcoreMEDHOK_MHK_Audit as ma
   Where cast(ma.AUDITDATETIME as Date) >= '2021/08/15'
   
)
SELECT
  DISTINCT id,  
  regexp_substr(MHK_CONTENT, '.*<b>\K.*') -- trim everything up to '<b>'
FROM TABLE (RegExp_Split_To_Table(t.ID, t.MHK_CONTENT, '<\/b>', 'i')
     RETURNS (ID BIGINT, tok_num INTEGER, 
MHK_CONTENT VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET LATIN)) AS t   ```

---[Teradata Database] [9134] Input exceeds the buffer size limit.
````

Answer (score 0):

Extending the SQL based on your previous question, this seems to be what you want:

```
with t as
 (
   select MHKAUDITLOGINTERNALID  as id, cast(MHK_CONTENT as clob) as MHK_CONTENT
   from vcoreMEDHOK_MHK_Audit as ma
   Where cast(ma.AUDITDATETIME as Date) >= '2021/08/15'
   -- Where ma.AUDITDATETIME >= DATE '2021-08-15'
   -- recommended to use DATE literals, the timestamp is here automatically converted to date  
   
)

select regexp_replace(Token, '<b>|<\/b>') -- remove tags
   ,dt.* 
FROM TABLE (RegExp_Split_To_Table(t.id, t.MHK_CONTENT,'<BR\/> *', 'i') -- split whenever '<BR/>' occurs 
RETURNS ( id INT, TokenNum INT,
         Token VARCHAR(32000) CHARACTER SET LATIN)
        ) AS dt
```

Regarding the error: Try to increase the size token size to the maximum.

Comment: [Teradata Database] [9134] Output exceeds buffer limit.

Comment: Hard to tell without details: What's the DDL of MHK_CONTENT and what's its maximum CHAR_LENGTH?

Comment: VARCHAR(35000) is USE Teradata SQL. Other than that I'm clueless. Im using a view. Got remove the <BR>'s too <BR>NoteID: 2289574</BR><BR>Action: Add</BR><BR>NoteType: Nurse Note</BR><BR>Note:

Comment: If it's a VarChar(35000) it must be LATIN (UNICODE is limited to 32000) and there's no need to cast to a CLOB. Increase Token to `VARCHAR(35000) CHARACTER SET LATIN`.

Comment: Your data showed only <b>,</b> and <BR/>. You must show exactly how these are nested.

Comment: agreed I regretted after sending that i thought geez i could just keep adjusting, ended up 8000. Then i ended up using: RegExp_Split_To_Table(t.id, t.MHK_CONTENT,'<b>|<\/b>|<BR>|</BR>*', 'i') sometimes its just better to go get some fresh air and come back to it. thank you sir.